# Setting field size (per column) while generating table in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am trying to export my Database as an .dbf by using a VBA script, but the dbf requires the database to have certain values for the column size.

When I leave the columns as they are in Access, I get an error saying

```
field will not fit in record
```

How can I set the column size for each column seperatly? Preferably while generating the table, so I don't have to do it manually everytime i generate a new table with queries

And where do I set them? (in a Query or in SQL?)

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit:

I have made sure that its the field size value that is giving me the error. I changed all the field size values manually by opening the table in Design View.

So now the second part of my question is becoming more crucial. Wether or not it is possible to set the field size while generating the table.

---

Edit2:

I am currently using SQL in a query to create the table as followed:

```
SELECT * INTO DB_Total
FROM Tags_AI_DB;
```

After the initial `DB_Total` is made, I use several `Insert into` queries to add other rows:

```
INSERT INTO DB_TOTAL
SELECT a.*
FROM Tags_STS_ENA_DB AS a 
LEFT JOIN DB_TOTAL AS b 
ON a.NAME = b.NAME
WHERE b.NAME IS NULL;
```

If I set the column values in the `DB_Total` table while generating it with the `Select into` query, will they still have those values after using the `Insert Into` queries to insert more rows?

---

Edit3:

I decided (after a few of your suggestions and some pointers from colleagues, that it would be better to first make my table and afterwards update this table with queries.

However, it seems like I have run into a dead end with Access, this is the code I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE DB_Total ("NAME" char(79),"TYPE" char(16), "UNIT" char(31), 
"ADDR" char(254), "RAW_ZERO" char(11), "RAW_FULL" char(11), "ENG_ZERO" char(11), 
"ENG_FULL" char(11), "ENG_UNIT" char(8), "FORMAT" char(11), "COMMENT" char(254), 
"EDITCODE" char(8), "LINKED" char(1), "OID" char(10), "REF1" char(11), "REF2" char(11),
"DEADBAND" char(11), "CUSTOM" char(128), "TAGGENLINK" char(32), "CLUSTER" char(16), 
"EQUIP" char(254), "ITEM" char(63), "HISTORIAN" char(6), 
"CUSTOM1" char(254), "CUSTOM2" char(254), "CUSTOM3" char(254), "CUSTOM4" char(254), 
"CUSTOM5" char(254), "CUSTOM6" char(254), "CUSTOM7" char(254), "CUSTOM8" char(254))
```

These are all the columns required for me to make a DBF file that is accepted by the application we are using it with.

You'll understand my sadness when this generated the following error:

```
Record is too large
```

Is there anything I can do to make this table work?

Comment: Show us the vba script that creates the table

Comment: @twoleggedhorse I edited my Question with more details on the project

Comment: Try changing all the CHAR(x) to VARCHAR(x)

Comment: That seems to work! Care to explain to me the difference? Aren't they exactly the same if you "bind" the size of the char with the size restriction (64) behind it?

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE

The maximum record size for Access 2007 is around 2kB (someone will no doubt correct that value)
When you create CHAR(255) it will use 255 bytes of space regardless as to what is in the field.
By contrast, VARCHARs do not use up space (only enough to define them) until you put something in the field, they grow dynamically.

Changing the `CHAR(x)`s to `VARCHAR(x)`s you will shrink the length of your table to within permitted values. Be aware that you may come into trouble if the row you are trying to insert is larger than the 2kB limit.

---

### Previous

The way to specify column lengths when generating the table is to use a `CREATE TABLE` statement instead of a `SELECT * INTO`.

```
CREATE TABLE DB_Total
(
 Column1Name NVARCHAR(255) --Use whatever datatype and length you need
,Column2Name NUMERIC(18,0) --Use whatever datatype and length you need
,...
) ;

INSERT INTO DB_Total
....
```

If you use a `SELECT * INTO` statement, SQL will use whatever field lengths and types it finds in the existing data.

It is also better practice to list the column names in your insert statement, so instead of

```
INSERT INTO DB_TOTAL
SELECT a.*
```

You should put:

```
INSERT INTO DB_Total
       (
        Column1Name
       ,Column2Name
       ,...
       )
SELECT  a.Column1Name
       ,a.Column2Name
       ,...
FROM   ...
WHERE  ... ;
```

Comment: I can not use the code you just gave me; I use  `CREATE TABLE DB_Total`  after that, I define all of my columns and values:

`CREATE TABLE DB_Total ("NAME" char(79),"TYPE" char(16), "UNIT" char(31)` (small part of the code) and after that, I have `INSERT INTO DB_Total`

But this gives me an error: `The instruction CREATE TABLE has a syntax error` after wich it highlites `INSERT`

Comment: @Gutanoth Try putting a terminator ; after the create table ..(columns.. ); I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Still the same error, is it even possible in Access2007 to do multiple actions in 1 Query? If i don't enter the "insert into" part, it tells me there needs to be at least 1 execute query

Comment: @Gutanoth What does your VBA script with the SQL look like?

Comment: So, the `char`command reserves 255 bits space, despite the restrictions I have given them?

Comment: @Gutanoth Not quite, CHAR(11) uses 11 bytes, char(254) uses 254 bytes. Your total is 3280 bytes. You can also use TEXT (MEMO in Access) datatype to get around the restriction. The TEXT datatype is stored outside the table but within the database and a pointer is kept in the table.

Answer (score 1):

In *Edit2*, you indicated your process starts with a "make table" (`SELECT INTO`) query which creates `DB_Total` and loads it with data from `Tags_AI_DB`.  Then you run a series of "append" (`INSERT`) queries to add data from other tables.

Now your problem is that you need specific field size settings for `DB_Total`, but it is impossible to define those sizes with a "make table" query.

I think you should create `DB_Total` one time and set the field sizes as you wish.  Do that manually with the table in Design View, or execute a `CREATE TABLE` statement if you prefer.

Then forget about the "make table" query and use only "append" queries to add the data.

If the issue is that this is a recurring operation and you want to discard previous data before importing the new, execute `DELETE FROM DB_Total` instead of `DROP TABLE DB_Total`.  That will allow you to preserve the structure of the (now empty) `DB_Total` table so you needn't fiddle with setting the field sizes again.

Seems to me the only potential issue then might be if the structure of the source tables changes.  If that happens, revise the structure of `DB_Total` so that it's compatible again.

Comment: I have tried generating a new (empty) table, with field sizes, but for some reason this gives me an error. (See edit3)

Comment: That error occurs after you've loaded all your data into `DB_Total` and you're trying to export it to DBF.  Is that correct?  Do you know if there is a dBase limit on the combined width of all the field values in a record?

Comment: No, the error occures right after Executing the query. If I open a fresh access database,wich is totally empty, and paste the `CREATE TABLE` code into a new query, access gives me an error after executing the query